# What’s the point of mixed-type lists

Tags: list, types, casting, static-typing, dynamic-typing

Some languages like Python allow you to define mixed type lists:

```py
mixed = [1, 'a', 2, 'b']
```

While other languages would require that all elements of a list be of the same type.

```py
numbers = [1, 2]
letters = ['a', 'b']
```

My question is: what’s a valid use case of mixed type lists? I’ve only seen them used in examples.

It seems to me that mixing types in a list is not a good  practice and if you have need for it, you’d probably be better off refactoring your code.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a heterogenous list that you have probably seen yourself thousands of times without realizing it, is the *argument list* of a subroutine call or message send: for example, in

```python
add_element_to_list(list, element)
```

The argument list `list :: element :: Nil` is a *heterogeneous list* of type `List[T] :: T :: Nil`.

You *could* also represent an argument list as a *tuple*, i.e. in the above example, the argument list would be the 2-tuple (aka "pair") `(list, element)` of type `List[T] × T`, but tuples have some limitations. For example, tuples are generally thought of as a single unit, not a collection. But, there are legitimate reasons you might want to iterate over the arguments in an arguments list.

Some languages / collections libraries *do* allow you to iterate over a tuple, for example, in Python, tuples are considered sequence types, and thus are iterable. Scala also has the `productIterator` method that lets you iterate over *any* product type (not just tuples).

But now we're back to square one: if we want to iterate over a tuple, then we need an iterator where the elements it yields can have different types. And an iterator is essentially the same thing as a (lazy) list, so now we have essentially re-introduced heterogeneous lists!

However, there is a probably more well-known use of heterogeneous lists, or more general, heterogeneous collections: database access.

The paper [Strongly Typed Heterogenous Collections](https://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/HList-ext.pdf) by Oleg Kiselyov, Ralf Lämmel, and Keean Schupke contains not only an implementation of heterogenous lists in Haskell, but also a motivating example of when, why and how you would use HLists. In particular, they are using it for type-safe compile-time checked database access. (Think LINQ, in fact, the paper they are referencing *is* the Haskell paper by Erik Meijer et al that led to LINQ.)

Quoting from the introductory paragraph of the HLists paper:

> Here is an open-ended list of typical examples that call for heterogeneous collections:
>
> - A symbol table that is supposed to store entries of different types is heterogeneous. It is a finite map, where the result type depends on the argument value.
> - An XML element is heterogeneously typed. In fact, XML elements are nested collections that are constrained by regular expressions and the 1-ambiguity property.
> - Each row returned by an SQL query is a heterogeneous map from column names to cells. The result of a query is a homogeneous stream of heterogeneous rows.
> - Adding an advanced object system to a functional language requires heterogeneous collections of a kind that combine extensible records with subtyping and an enumeration interface.

Note that the Python example you gave in your question is really not a heterogenous list in the sense that the word is commonly used, since Python doesn't *have* (static) types. It is a *weakly typed* or *untyped* list. In fact, in some sense, it is actually a *homogenous* list, since all elements are of the same type: depending on your interpretation, all elements have no type, all elements have the type *Object*, or all elements have the type *Dynamic* – but in all cases, they all have the same type. You are then forced to perform casts or unchecked `isinstance` tests or something like that, in order to actually be able to meaningfully work with the elements, which makes them weakly typed.